# copy all highlighted text in a word document and paste it to another document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am very close with achieving this task. The following vba code does copy the text to a new Word document. But I would like the text in the new document to maintain the highlighted colour it was in the original document.

I would be most grateful for assistance.

```
Sub CopyHighlightsToOtherDoc()
Dim ThisDoc As Document
Dim ThatDoc As Document
Dim r As Range
Set ThisDoc = ActiveDocument
Set r = ThisDoc.Range
Set ThatDoc = Documents.Add
With r.Find
   .Text = ""
   .Highlight = True
   Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
      ThatDoc.Range.InsertAfter r.Text & vbCrLf
      r.Collapse 0
   Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Range.FormattedText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.formattedtext) property to get text and formatting.

The syntax is `ThisRange.FormattedText = ThatRange.FormattedText`

EDIT:

```
Sub CopyHighlightsToOtherDoc()
    Dim ThisDoc As Document
    Dim ThatDoc As Document
    Dim r As Range
    Set ThisDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set r = ThisDoc.Range
    Set ThatDoc = Documents.Add
    With r
        With .Find
            .Text = ""
            .Highlight = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            ThatDoc.Range.Characters.Last.FormattedText = .FormattedText
            ThatDoc.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            .Collapse 0
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Timothy, but I do not know what I should replace with your suggestion. Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: Hi Timothy, amazing, I am trying to learn from what you have written, but how can I improve what you have written so that the destination document has all the text grouped by their highlighted colour? Thank you in advance.